# Que es lo tengo que hacer para poder crear una app? Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.7, exe

Recientemente estoy aprendiendo a programar y he creado un pequeño código, cuando lo ejecuto, no ocurre ningún error en la pc que tiene python, así que quise crear una app.

El exe funcionaba bien en mi pc pero cuando lo pase a otra pc que no tiene python me da un error ¨falied to load script main.py¨ necesito saber que mas necesita mi código o que otros archivos tengo que añadir para que el exe funcione en otras pcs sin python.

**Este es el comando que use para crear el exe** :
*pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --name CalculadoraPI **main**.py*

Mi carpeta con contiene :
resources (ahi dentro tengo piImage.ico)
main.py (es el codigo principal)

El codigo de main.py es :

```py
import math
from decimal import Decimal
import decimal
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, Frame
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
from tkinter import filedialog

def calcpi():
    valorPi = int(nVecesPi.get())
    valorN = valorPi
    # Intente poner 100000 y mi pc no aguanto.
    # Trabajar con la precisión adecuada
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 2*(valorN+3)

    a = Decimal(0)
    i = 3
    pi = Decimal(0)
    a = Decimal(0)

    while True:
        piold = pi
        x1= (2+a).sqrt()
        x = (2-x1).sqrt()
        y = Decimal(pow(2,i-1))
        pi = x*y
        if piold==pi:
            break
        a = (2+a).sqrt()
        i = i + 1 

    print(f"Detenido tras {i} iteraciones")
    print('El valor aproximado de pi es ')
    print(pi)
    # Este es el valor real con 65 digitos #
    # print("3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923")
    resultadoDePi.delete(0,'end')
    resultadoDePi.insert(0,pi)

calculadora = Tk()
calculadora.title("Calculadora de Pi (Por MARCUS MATOS)")
calculadora.geometry("400x400")
calculadora.config(bg="#B8B8B8")
calculadora.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\MarcoAntonio\Desktop\CalculadoraPi\resources\piImage.ico')

calculadora.mainloop()

más código...
```

Esta es la carpeta que aparecen después de crear el ejecutable
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SOes! ¿Cómo estás tratando de crear el ejecutable? ¿Cuál es tu código? Los colaboradores del sitio no conocen nada del contexto fuera del texto de tu pregunta, hay tantas cosas que podrían estar mal, por favor lee  [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que se te pueda ayudar de una manera realista.

Comment: @FranAcuna Gracias por la bienvenida. He leído el como preguntar y he formulado una pregunta mejor. Espero que se pueda entender mejor mi problema.

Comment: Qué extraño! ¿Cómo queda la carpeta que tiene el ejecutable?

Comment: Empaqueta la app con *pyinstaller* sin el argumento `--windowed` para ver el error en la consola y así corregirlo.

Comment: He modificado mi pregunta de acuerdo a tus observaciones y espero que se entienda y me puedan ayudar a crear mi ejecutable sea portable

Answer (score 0):

El error procede de esta línea:

```py
calculadora.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\MarcoAntonio\Desktop\CalculadoraPi\resources\piImage.ico)
```

Estás utilizando un *path absoluto* para tu icono, y seguramente en el otro equipo no tienes ese icono en esa dirección. **El *path* del icono (y de cualquier recurso) debe ser relativo al de tu *script* para que el ejecutable funcione independientemente de su ubicación**:

```py
calculadora.iconbitmap('resources/piImage.ico')
```

**NOTA:** Si quieres utilizar un *path absoluto* tienes que obtenerlo en tiempo de ejecución: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'resources/piImage.ico')`.

Dado que estás utilizando el argumento `--onefile`, los recursos del ejecutable serán descomprimidos en el directorio temporal definido en `sys._MEIPASS`, por lo que debes añadir lo siguiente al inicio de tu *script*:

```py
import sys, os

# Si exite sys._MEIPASS estamos ejecutando el .exe creado con PyInstaller
# y en ese caso interesa que el directorio de trabajo sea sys._MEIPASS,
# que es donde se descomprime el directorio "resources" en tiempo de ejecución

if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```

Esto es así porque `sys._MEIPASS` es un atributo que crea *pyinstaller* y solo existe una vez que has *compilado* la aplicación.

Finalmente tienes que añadir el directorio *resources* como recurso del ejecutable:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --add-data "resources;resources" --name CalculadoraPI main.py
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero despues de los cambios sugeridos me sale el error : File "c:\Users\MarcoAntonio\Desktop\CalculadoraPi\__main__.py", line 59, in main
    calculadora.iconbitmap("./resources/piImage.ico")
  File "C:\Users\MarcoAntonio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2080, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "./resources/piImage.ico" not defined

Comment: Me equivoqué en el comando de compilación, puse `--add-data "resources;."`, en realidad sería: `pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --add-data "resources;resources" --name CalculadoraPI main.py`. Ya lo he corregido en el comentario. Un saludo!